# How to access camera from Electron's main process

Tags: javascript, electron

How to access user's camera from the main process (i.e. `main.js`) in Electron, without opening a window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There are a number of APIs that have to be run in the renderer process, such as Notifications, and it looks like accessing a camera is one of those. If you don't want to actually show a BrowserWindow, pass the `show:false` option ([documented here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/ad3b3e016261e746e667f6a2f8df33cae1e5f0eb/docs/api/browser-window.md))

Here's a sample app using the camera: https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/camera.

Comment: For some reason, camera permission on macOS is not persistent (I am asked to allow camera access each time I run app or reload window). Would you happen to know why?

Comment: @sunknudsen I don't because I haven't done Electron development in awhile. My best guess would be maybe you don't have camera permissions in your app entitlements file so it's always requesting it?